# Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime.Serialization after publishing via Windows Azure

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I published my solution using Windows Azure sdk and now I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details**: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> **Source Error**: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Assembly Load Trace**: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' could not be loaded.
>
> **WRN**: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> **Stack Trace**: [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>      System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +371
>      System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +19
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +319
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +203
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Int32 attributeCtorToken, Boolean mustBeInheritable) +745
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit) +300
>      System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateMessageDescription(MethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean isAsync, Boolean isTask, Type taskTResult, XmlName returnValueName, String defaultNS, String action, XmlName wrapperName, String wrapperNamespace, MessageDirection direction) +415
>      System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateOperationDescription(ContractDescription contractDescription, MethodInfo methodInfo, MessageDirection direction, ContractReflectionInfo reflectionInfo, ContractDescription declaringContract) +1895
>      System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateOperationDescriptions(ContractDescription contractDescription, ContractReflectionInfo reflectionInfo, Type contractToGetMethodsFrom, ContractDescription declaringContract, MessageDirection direction) +276
>      System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateContractDescription(ServiceContractAttribute contractAttr, Type contractType, Type serviceType, ContractReflectionInfo& reflectionInfo, Object serviceImplementation) +1307
>      System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(Type contractType, Type serviceType, Object serviceImplementation) +289
>      System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract(Type contractType, Type serviceType) +192
>      System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implementedContracts) +591
>      System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +166
>      System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +474
>      System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +42
>      System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +569
>      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1435
>      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +76
>      System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +901
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/CarManagerApi.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
>      System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +622882
>      System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +196075
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +282

I can't find the error in the code.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was different .Net frameworks in projects on the same solution

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the framework 2.0 isn't installed on remote machine.

Comment: the remote machine is on windows azure

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem using Newtonsoft.Json in a library. The library worked fine on Windows, but died with this error when used with Mono on OS X.

In order to get it to run I had to copy the actual System.Runtime.Serialization.dll into the application directory.

Obviously it's not a great solution but it works.